# Is automating updates in apt and snap a good idea?

Tags: apt, bash, upgrade, updates, snap

To save on some typing on every update I've created the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

patching(){
    apt-get update -y;
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get dist-upgrade -y;
    snap refresh
    apt autoremove -y
};

patching;
```

(Question 0: The script runs through but are there any glaring oversights or necessary improvements?)

**Question 1**: Is this a good Idea? If so, why aren't `update` and `autoremove` baked into `dist-upgrade` by default?

**Question 2**: Are there things that can go wrong when running the script as opposed to executing the commands individually?

Comment: There's `unattended-upgrades` for apt, and snaps update automatically.

Comment: The script duplicates automatic services that are already running on a stock Ubuntu system, but the script has fewer protections. An unwise choice of apt source might damage your system without warning.

Comment: @user535733 That's a valid answer. I did run into trouble with dependencies eventually. Haven't seen your comment in time, unfortunately. Might be a good idea to formalize it for anyone who may come across this thread in the future.

Comment: It seems part of the existing answer "*As long as your sources are under control....*" Unwise source decisions by humans are at the root of many support questions.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your sources are under control, this should be fine.

I'm running a similar script on my own server every week:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
apt-get autoremove -y
apt-get clean
snap refresh
```

This has been running for over 3 years, without major issues.

However, you should occasionally review the `apt` logs to see what is installed. At one point, some dependencies were changed, and a bunch of new packages got installed (and then removed some weeks later).

In `apt`, the commands `update`, `upgrade` and `autoremove` are separate simply to allow more control.

If you want to be completely sure the script will run as planned, you could run a "pre-script" that does a dry run, and save output to logs, like this:

```
apt-get update >> /path/to/logfile
apt-get dist-upgrade -y --dry-run >> /path/to/logfile
apt-get autoremove -y --dry-run >> /path/to/logfile
apt-get clean --dry-run >> /path/to/logfile
snap refresh >> /path/to/logfile
```

Then you can review everything before the actual script is running. In this case, leave out `apt-get update` from the real script.